# Paste From Clipboard not always working

Tags: windows-7, clipboard, visual-studio

So, this has been driving me crazy for a bit, but now I have a repro:

On my work machine, I cannot copy/paste some text into some applications.

Example:
If I click on the address bar in Windows Explorer and then copy (to copy the path to the directory that is in focus), I cannot paste the string into LinqPad.  However, I can paste the string into the text editor into Visual Studio.  I can then copy the string from Visual Studio into LinqPad.  Crazy??

Stats:

- Windows 7 64bit/Pro/all updates in Microsoft
- Update Belongs to a domain (Group Policy thing??)
- I am an admin, but I run with UAC enabled (default setting)
- None of the apps in question are running "elevated"